# Using Regular Expressions with Coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

using REMatchNoCase,
how can you write a Regular Expressions to find in a string the following

S##E## or S##E##E## ...
sample 
S01E01 or S07E16E17

S and E can be upper or lower case
and there can be spaces, such as 
S 01 E01

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the regular expression you'll need:
"(?i)(^S\d{2}E\d{2}$)|(^S\d{2}E\d{2}E\d{2}$)"

Comment: That'll only work if the match is the *entire* string, not "in a string" as per the requirement.  I've posted a slightly tweaked version (plus in a CF-specific context).

Comment: The requirement also mentioned spaces, but that needs some clarification about the pattern.

Comment: @Leigh: so it did.  I have updated my answer.  Cheers for the heads-up.

Comment: @Adam - Yep, that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
matches = reMatchNoCase("S\d{2}(?:E\d{2}){1,2}", string);
```

Update: Leigh is quite right in his comment that I missed the bit of the requirement wherein optional spaces could be present.  Although the requirement is not clear as to where the spaces might validly be present.  To respect the example exactly as stated, the regex would be adjusted to:

```
S\s*\d{2}(?:E\d{2}){1,2}
```

(note the inclusion of \s*, meaning zero or more whitespace characters). If there are more positions the spaces might appear, just insert \s* in those positions too.